# RegEx to match everything between first occurrence of two words, both of which appear more than once

Tags: .net, regex

I have an email that comes in in which I need to extract the data. I'm using Nintex Workflows RegEx action with the extract function selected. I use a online .NET regex tester to validate that it will work in the workflow.

My data is like this.

```
There is some extra information here that is not needed

WHEN: 12 12:34Z - 12 45:67Z May 16 (I need everything after WHEN:\s until EOL)
WHERE: Around (I do not need this line)

There is some extra information here that is not needed

WHEN: 12 12:34Z - 12 45:67Z May 16 (Duplicate data not needed)
WHERE: Around (I do not need this line)

There is some extra information here that is not needed
```

I'm using the following code to capture in between two key words. The problem is that it still matches the duplicate data `(?s)(?<=WHEN:\s).*?(?=WHERE:)`

[.NET Regex Sample](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fs)(%3f%3c%3dWHEN%3a%5cs).*%3f(%3f%3dWHERE%3a)&i=There+is+some+extra+information+here+that+is+not+needed%0d%0aWHEN%3a+12+12%3a34Z+-+12+45%3a67Z+May+16+(I+need+the+date+only)%0d%0aWHERE%3a+Around+(I+do+not+need+this+line)%0d%0aThere+is+some+extra+information+here+that+is+not+needed%0d%0aWHEN%3a+12+12%3a34Z+-+12+45%3a67Z+May+16+(Duplicate+data+not+needed)%0d%0aWHERE%3a+Around+(I+do+not+need+this+line)%0d%0aThere+is+some+extra+information+here+that+is+not+needed)

Comment: I don't need to capture the `WHERE:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should grab data after first 'WHEN: ':

```
^WHEN:\s(.*?)
```